Teen discovers underground world under her father's house
I watched this 15-20 years ago on cassette beta.
A teen is working with her roller skates in California. One day she learns her father has dead but she hasn't seen him for years. She goes to his house and discovers a door in his room going underground. She falls from door when she opens it to the underground and her glasses are broken. She meets an handsome boy there and discovers an underground city where her father has researched for years. Then she finds her father. People eats insects and they haven't seen the sun ever. The people here don't know the surface world.
What is the name of this movie?

Do you mean VHS cassette tape, or literally Beta(max)?  A betamax movie is likely to be quite old - probably 70's or early 80's.

What do you mean by "One day she learns her father has dead but she hasn't seen him for years."?

"Working with her roller skates". The story otherwise reminds me of some Alice in Wonderland-variant. I recently watched Alice where she finds her long-gone father working as a researcher in the "underground". Obviously not the right movie, since it was never released on betamax...

@Rathony I guess my interpretation would be "She has not seen her father in many years, and one day she learns that he has died."

It's Alien from L.A. (1988)
Alien From L.A. is a science fiction film with Kathy Ireland.



Plot (Wikipedia) :
Wanda Saknussemm (Ireland) is a nerdy social misfit with large glasses
  and a intolerable squeaky voice who lives in Los Angeles and
  works at a diner. After being dumped by her boyfriend for "not having
  a sense of adventure", Wanda is informed by a letter that her father,
  an archaeologist, has died. She flies to North Africa and while going
  through her father's belongings, she finds his notes about Atlantis,
  apparently an alien ship that crashed millennia ago and sank into the
  center of the Earth. Wanda comes across a chamber beneath her father's
  apartment and accidentally sets off a chain of events that ultimately
  cause her to fall into a deep hole.
An unharmed Wanda wakes up deep within the Earth to find Gus (William
  R. Moses), a miner whom she protects from being slain by two people.
  Gus, who has a very inconsistent Australian accent, agrees to help
  Wanda find her father, whom she believes is alive and trapped
  underground. Wanda soon discovers that both she and her father are
  believed to be spies planning an invasion of Atlantis. During her
  adventures, Wanda's appearance changes from nerdy to attractive (by
  removing her glasses and using a steam vent to clean her skin). People
  from the surface world are referred to as "aliens" by Atlanteans, who
  appear virtually identical to surface dwellers, and when Wanda is
  overheard talking about Malibu Beach by a low-life informant (Janie Du
  Plessis), she soon becomes a hunted woman and must dodge efforts at
  capture, both from the mysterious "Government House" and from thugs in
  the pay of the crime lord Mambino (Deep Roy). During these sequences,
  many references to Wanda's "big bones" are made, as though it were a
  trait by which she could be identified; however, no obvious physical
  distinction between Wanda and the Atlanteans is noticeable.
Wanda's efforts at escape are aided by Charmin (Thom Matthews), a
  handsome rogue who (briefly) assists her flight and falls for Wanda.
  She is ultimately captured by the evil General Pykov (Du Plessis
  again), who wants to kill both Wanda and her incarcerated father. The
  Atlantean leader decides to free Wanda and her father, provided they
  remain quiet about Atlantis. Gus shows up and helps the duo escape
  while fighting off General Pykov and her soldiers. Wanda and her
  father board a ship that takes them back to the surface and the film
  ends with Wanda on the beach, wearing a bikini and a sarong. She
  refuses the advances of her ex-boyfriend and is soon reunited with
  Charmin, who inexplicably appears on a motorcycle.






IMDB
Trailer
